# IllegalStateException при создании файла в Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать файлы в Internal Storage, чтобы записать в него ключи шифрования RSA. Создаю файлы так:

```
try {
    final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
    final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    File privateKeyFile = new File(context.getFilesDir());
    File publicKeyFile = new File(md5(nickname.getText().toString()) + "_public_key");
    String tmp = privateKeyFile.getAbsolutePath();
    if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
        privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    boolean result_private = privateKeyFile.createNewFile();
    if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
        publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    boolean result_public = publicKeyFile.createNewFile();
    BufferedWriter pubOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile)));
    pubOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPublic().getEncoded()));
    pubOut.flush();
    pubOut.close();
    BufferedWriter privOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile)));
    privOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
    privOut.flush();
    privOut.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Программа вылетает на этой строчке:

```
boolean result_private = privateKeyFile.createNewFile();
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
 08-04 00:09:56.631 2184-2208/com.example.jack.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe99e6de0  
    08-04 00:10:01.246 2184-2184/com.example.jack.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
Process: com.example.jack.myapplication, PID: 2184
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
  at com.example.jack.myapplication.register.onClick_register(register.java:202)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корневая проблема тут

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference

```
File publicKeyFile = new File(md5(nickname.getText().toString()) + "_public_key");
```

Проверьте под дебаггером, что у вас в nickname и что возвращает nickname.getText()

Comment: Я писал даже так: File publicKeyFile = new File("ololo"); результат такой же

Comment: А вон тот кусок кода, который в вопросе, он внутри метода onClick_register? Потому как NPE вылетает внутри него. Возможно до приведенного куска кода просто не доходит

Comment: да он внутри onClick_register